# How applications are able to find a SQL Server DB - one VM to another (setup or configuration question)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, networking

In my company we have 3 virtual machines (application, business, DB).
Been trying to understand how our software app running in my machine which uses a simple text file with connection string is able to communicate to another server like the database server to connect to MS SQL installed there.

If I login to Business server and run a simple powershell to query the SQL db, it is able to connect as well.

My question is, how does the visibility of MS SQL Server (running on our DB Server/vm) available to the Application and Business servers? Was it done by installing some components to application/business server and making bits of configuration to be able talk to the SQL server from another VM? What's normally the setup here?

Sorry, you might be wondering why I'm asking you guys and not the developers in my team, but they don't know either, because they run the client app and it connects to the DB using the connection string. The DBA/Infrastructure guys were the ones who did some setup but can't be bothered or won't want to be bothered.

Thanks

Comment: client app is running on C# 7.0,  .Net Framework 4.8, VM no idea about the details, SQL DB Version 12.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify more details in the next format :

- Language, Tools used.
- Version and name of framework.
- Db version.
- VM Machine version and type. (Oracle, VMWare, etc)

The first thing to check it's your connection outside your app and inside each VM.
If you reach from the VM to the Database allocated in the external server that means the infra team has made their job.

If not, your vm setup has to be in a net configuration that allows your vm to have access or reach the net where you're central server with the db it's allocated.

Take a look at : https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/3477/which-type-of-networking-should-you-use-for-your-virtual-machine/

If the second one it's the case, this it's not a Developer task. it cames mores from the Infra side and you should scalate the issue with your pm to the corresponding department.

Those should be your first items to work on. Best!.

Comment: Sorry, your comment got me confused even more. So how did the setup work , is it like 1)  Installing SQL Sever on VM1 (DB Server) 2) Configuring connections by installing SQL components so the DB Server and databases are accessible and visible outside that VM 3) Installing other SQL components to VM2 (Application server) and VM3 (Business server) so that any stand-alone application installed and running on those 2 VMs (VM2, VM3) can easily find the database by using the connection string in app.config of the stand-alone application?  Thanks

Comment: I don't see why a DB should be installed in a separate server from the business Server. It seems the more easiest way. Install the SQL server in the Same VM3 Where your application it's running. Unless the cost Application + DB are above the VM resources. Once made that , you should check that VM1, VM2 reach The application and DB on VM3. By setting just the connections string to that host of the VM3 on each (VM1, VM2) .

Comment: The way they've configured it is each of these runs on separate VMs, so the client app is on VM2 with copies of Business services DLL (VM3) and these DLLs have the connection string in the config file which then talks to VM1 (DB Server). So to simply understand, how does the Business server able to find the DB server with just that connection string? Is it using a special SQL component or DLL (installed in business server) that acts as connection/channel?

Comment: You should have a connection string in your code or definitions xml in the BS Application. Which uses some driver as lib. I couldn't say without looking at the code exactly. But that it's. First test that you reach from BS Server to the DB Server alone by making a connection through sql plus or else.

By interpreting as you say.
VM2 : Client App + Clients of ws in VM3. 
VM3 : WS dlls wich connect to the db in VM1
VM1 : DB Server .
I've added some useful tags to your question [C#], [#Networking], [#VM] use them as well.
Let me know if that helps, best.